# Can I configure a Bluemix DevOps toolchain with Enterprise Github?

Tags: ibm-cloud, devops

When I create a Bluemix DevOps toolchain, it automatically includes GitHub (public) in the toolchain.  I would like to use my company's Enterprise Github. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are using the public Bluemix (in on of the three regions).

If yes, the only repo that can be used is the public Github.

If you are using a dedicated/local Bluemix you would have the option of working with your enterprise Github.

Comment: There is a similar question on Questions and answer (https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/328130/how-can-i-add-source-from-githubibmcom-repository/?smartspace=bluemix). Check the answers there to see if they are applicable.

Answer (score 0):

Yesterday we rolled out a new feature that allows you to hook your GHE in with Bluemix Public (assuming networking is open).

From the toolchain catalog, when you select the GitHub tile, now you will see a GitHub server dropdown. From this dropdown, chose "Add a custom server...", provide a title, root URL, and a personal access token, then click "Save custom integration". Now you should be all set to create new/fork/clone or link with existing repositories on your GHE.